# Morphological opening and closing equation in latex

Tags: equations, symbols

I want to add the equations of morphological opening and morphological closing in my latex document. I found few symbols such as `\oplus` but couldn't complete the whole equations. Here are the equations. Any code or source to these symbols will be helpful.  [image: Morphological Closing]  [image: Morphological Opening]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A \bullet B & = (A \oplus B) \ominus B \\
A \circ B & = (A \ominus B) \oplus B
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, for finding symbols, [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is extremely useful, as is the [comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive).

Comment: Thanks, brother. It worked for me. But, can you tell me the significance of the '&' symbols there? It worked for me both with and without these '&' symbols.

Comment: You're welcome! The `&` symbols are used to indicate alignment in the `align` environment (from `amsmath`); they make sure that the two equal signs are flush below one another here.

Comment: @Nieb_Hasan_077 BTW, if the answer helped you, it'd be cool if you could "accept" it by clicking on the checkmark symbol. Cheers!

Comment: Sure brother. I was just waiting for other amazing solutions such as @Catree provided us below.

Answer (score 4):

A tip to know the Latex code from a Wikipedia equation is to look directly at the source code.

Example for the [opening operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Opening), you can click on the `edit` link of the section and directly see the [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mathematical_morphology&action=edit&section=8):

```
<math>A \circ B  = (A \ominus B) \oplus B.</math>
```

Comment: that's amazing. Does it kinda conclude that Wikipedia pages (or some part of it) are coded in latex?

Comment: @Nieb_Hasan_077 Yes, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula